# How to cross join using 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image]

i have 3 tables: customer,Barang and Det_Barang.

customer + barang = one to many

barang + det_barang = many to many

How to cross from the 3 table above? And the result as shown in the 4th table

Link SQL File : 
[Test.sql](https://www.dropbox.com/s/754sqtiqtnz48xg/test.sql?dl=0)

Comment: Please edit your question and include sample data and desired results.  I sincerely doubt that your really want a `cross join`.

Comment: yes i want to cross join, I try using this query : select customer.nama,test.* FROM customer CROSS JOIN (SELECT barang.no,det_barang,qty,det_barang.No_Cust FROM barang LEFT JOIN det_barang ON det_barang.No_barang = Barang.No) AS test ON test.No_Cust = customer.No 
but failed. The result is wrong

Comment: As I understand the `cross join` is something like `select * from table1, table2` where result set is the all possible combinations of all records from all tables used in the query? May be you mean `full join`?

Comment: I think you're looking for a combination of a `cross join` with a `left` `join`

Comment: @JimmyAndrianDavius Take a look at the answers and see which one fits your scenario and is the solution. Afterwards don't forget to upvote/mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.Nama AS Customer, b.No AS No_Barang, d.Qty
FROM customer c
JOIN barang b
LEFT JOIN det_barang d ON c.No = d.No_Cust AND b.No = d.No_Barang
ORDER BY c.No, b.No
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT c.nama
    ,b.no
    ,d.qty
FROM customer c
CROSS JOIN barang b
LEFT JOIN det_barang d ON c.no = d.no
    AND b.no = d.no_barang
ORDER BY c.nama, b.no;
```

You'll have to adjust the column names to match your table schema.

Also, here is a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7574a/1) with the result.

Comment: not work, [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'd.no' in 'on clause'

Comment: @JimmyAndrianDavius I said you have to adjust your column names to match your table's column names.